# Asynchronism in Action Script 3.0

Tags: multithreading, actionscript-3, actionscript, asynchronous, thread-safety

I wonder, how is asynchronism implemented in AS3? Lets take the `Timer` class. A timer runs asynchronously and dispatches some events. Seems like it creates a new thread for himself. And how are the functions, called when timer event occurs, being thread safe? How is thread safety implemented in AS3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AS3 now supports multi threading using "ActionScript Workers" in the latest build. You can see how it is used here in this preview...

http://www.bytearray.org/?p=4423

Answer (score 3):

AS3 [used to be] [not multithreaded](http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2008/01/threads_in_actionscript_3.html).

Prior to Flash Player 11.4, everything ran on the main (single) thread, which is why things like `Timer` classes could be [notoriously inaccurate](http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=910) if the CPU gets bogged down with some heavy processing.

As of Flash Player 11.4, [`Worker`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html) objects were introduced, providing the ability to create multiple threads.

Comment: I just want to note that these days we have access to the Worker class (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html) for concurrency.

Comment: I beg to differ http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html